# RuntimeError: dimension specified as 0 but tensor has no dimensions

Tags: pytorch

I was trying to Implement simple NN using the MNIST datasets and I keep getting this error
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
import torch
from torchvision import models
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torch import nn, optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
import helper

transform = transforms.ToTensor()

train_data = datasets.MNIST(root='data', train=True,
                                   download=True, transform=transform)
test_data = datasets.MNIST(root='data', train=False,
                                  download=True, transform=transform)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size = 20, shuffle=True)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_data, batch_size = 20, shuffle=True)
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net,self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(784,10)

    def forward(self,x):

        x = x.view(-1,784)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.log_softmax(x, dim = 1)
        return x


model = Net()
criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr = 0.003)

epochs = 20
model.train()
for epoch in range(epochs):
    train_loss = 0

    for image, lables in train_data:

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        output = model(image)
        loss = criterion(output, lables)
        loss.backwards()
        optimizer.step()
        train_loss += loss.item()*image.size(0)
    train_loss = train_loss/len(train_data.dataset)

    print('Epoch: {} \tTraining Loss: {:.6f}'.format(epoch+1, train_loss))
```

Here is the error
    RuntimeError: dimension specified as 0 but tensor has no dimensions

Comment: For the future: please report not only the exception thrown but also some of the stack trace. I had to run your code to get the context, and it's helpful for anyone answering to know straight away that the exception is thrown in `File "so.py", line 42, in <module>  loss = criterion(output, lables)`

Comment: I am almost 3 years late here. :). In case this helps out anyone who is looking for similar workaround, would like to say that I also had this issue and I had to use the loader (part of the coursework tbh). I looked around and found existing discussions on Github. Please find them below: 1. [Discussion 1](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/5552) 2. [Discussion 2](https://github.com/spro/practical-pytorch/issues/106) I tried the following. [TORCH.UNSQUEEZE](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html) The issue was resolved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue you're hitting directly is that NLL loss expects a `labels` (you're spelling it `lables` btw) tensor of at least 1 dimension and it's getting a 0-dimensional tensor (aka a scalar). If you see this kind of messages, it's good to just `print(output.shape, labels.shape)` for easier inspection. The source of this error is that you, probably by mistake, run `for image, labels in train_data` instead of `for image, labels in train_loader`. The consequence is that your data is not batched - batching the scalars coming out of `dataset` would create the missing dimension `NLLLoss` complains about.

Once we fix this, we proceed to fix `backwards` -> `backward` and finally `len(train_data.dataset)` -> `len(train_data)`. Then the loop works (if it's a reasonable net etc, I did not test).

As a side remark, you can combine `NLLLoss` and `log_softmax` by using [`CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss), which has the benefit of extra numerical stability.

Comment: One hack could be to use image and label as list e.g. `image = [image]` and `label = [label]` for model input. I had this issue and it was solved by doing so.