# AraBertV2: Dimension specified as 0 but tensor has no dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to use AraBert2 for a classification task, but it keeps giving me this error:

```
32 X = df["fully_cleaned_text_no_stopwords"].values
     33 y = df["target"].values
---> 34 datasets = [preprocess(text, label) for text, label in zip(X, y)]
     35 train_size = int(0.6 * len(datasets))
     36 test_size = len(datasets) - train_size

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataset.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    187 
    188     def __init__(self, *tensors: Tensor) -> None:
--> 189         assert all(tensors[0].size(0) == tensor.size(0) for tensor in tensors), "Size mismatch between tensors"
    190         self.tensors = tensors
    191 

IndexError: Dimension specified as 0 but tensor has no dimensions
```

The text samples and labels have the same shape, there is no empty values.

Here is my code:

```
model_name = "aubmindlab/bert-base-arabertv2"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, vocab_size=500)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name, num_labels=2)

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

max_length = 943

def preprocess(text, label):
    # tokenize the text
    tokens = tokenizer.encode_plus(
        text,
        max_length=max_length,
        padding="max_length",
        truncation=True,
        return_attention_mask=True,
        return_tensors="pt"
    )
    # create a tensor dataset
    dataset = TensorDataset(
        tokens["input_ids"],
        tokens["attention_mask"],
        torch.tensor(label)
    )
    return dataset

X = df["fully_cleaned_text_no_stopwords"].values
y = df["target"].values
datasets = [preprocess(text, label) for text, label in zip(X, y)]
train_size = int(0.6 * len(datasets))
test_size = len(datasets) - train_size
train_dataset, test_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(datasets, [train_size, test_size])
train_dataloader = DataLoader(
    train_dataset,
    sampler=RandomSampler(train_dataset),
    batch_size=32
)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(
    test_dataset,
    sampler=SequentialSampler(test_dataset),
    batch_size=32
)

optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=5e-5)

model.to(device)
model.train()
for epoch in range(25):
    for batch in train_dataloader:
        input_ids = batch[0].to(device)
        attention_mask = batch[1].to(device)
        labels = batch[2].to(device)
        outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=labels)
        loss = outputs.loss
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

model.eval()
y_true = []
y_pred = []
for batch in test_dataloader:
    input_ids = batch[0].to(device)
    attention_mask = batch[1].to(device)
    labels = batch[2].to(device)
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
    logits = outputs.logits
    predictions = torch.argmax(logits, dim=1)
    y_true.extend(labels.tolist())
    y_pred.extend(predictions.tolist())

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
precision = precision_score(y_true, y_pred)
recall = recall_score(y_true, y_pred)
f1 = f1_score(y_true, y_pred)

print("Accuracy:", accuracy)
print("Precision:", precision)
print("Recall:", recall)
print("F1 score:", f1)
```

I tried many solutions such as: ensuring there is no empty values and label column is always a tensor, but no result at all

Comment: Most probably there's one batch with only 1 input that causes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53841576/runtimeerror-dimension-specified-as-0-but-tensor-has-no-dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there's one batch with only 1 input that causes [RuntimeError: dimension specified as 0 but tensor has no dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53841576/runtimeerror-dimension-specified-as-0-but-tensor-has-no-dimensions)

You should be feeding in a batch of text instead of single text to the tokenizer, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import torch
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, RandomSampler, SequentialSampler, DataLoader

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"text": ["hallo welt", "hello world", "du hast", "J'ai", "I have"], "target": ["foo", "bar", "foo", "blah","bar"]})
df['labels'], _ = pd.factorize(df['target'].values)


tokenized_batch = tokenizer(
        list(df['text']),
        padding="max_length",
        truncation=True,
        return_attention_mask=True,
        return_tensors="pt"
    )

dataset = TensorDataset(
    tokenized_batch["input_ids"],
    tokenized_batch["attention_mask"],
    torch.tensor(list(df['labels']))
)

dl = DataLoader(
    dataset,
    sampler=SequentialSampler(dataset),
    batch_size=2
)


for batch in dl:
  print(batch)
```

Also, look into using [`datasets.Dataset` from Huggingface](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.10.0/en/package_reference/main_classes#datasets.Dataset.from_pandas) or https://pytorch.org/data/main/torchdata.datapipes.iter.html